# Xcode: How would I make a toggle button for this cocoscript app?

Tags: xcode, button, applescript

AppDelegate.applescript

```
--  iTunes Switcher
--
--  Created by admini on 11/13/12.
--  Copyright (c) 2012 Bdaniels. No rights reserved.
--  



script AppDelegate
    property parent : class "NSObject"

    on ButtonHandlerActivationOn_(sender)
        tell application "iTunes" to quit
        do shell script "/usr/bin/defaults write com.apple.iTunes StoreActivationMode -integer 1"
        delay 1
        do shell script "open -a itunes"
    end ButtonHandlerActivationOn

    on ButtonHandlerActivationOff_(sender)
        tell application "iTunes" to quit
        do shell script "/usr/bin/defaults write com.apple.iTunes StoreActivationMode -integer 0"
        delay 1
        do shell script "open -a itunes"
    end ButtonHandlerActivationOff




    on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
        -- Insert code here to initialize your application before any files are opened 
    end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

    on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
        -- Insert code here to do any housekeeping before your application quits 
        return current application's NSTerminateNow
    end applicationShouldTerminate_

end script
```

Here is a screen shot of the UI
https://i.stack.imgur.com/teos5.jpg

I would like to put a green light if the state is turned on. 
Any help on this would be great! There are two more buttons here, but I omitted them because I had "Too much code" in my post and stackoverflow would not let me post it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need an image, a green image. Add that to your project. In the code I'm using "green.png" as its name. Then add these so you can access NSImage methods and add an image to a button.

```
property NSImage : class "NSImage"
property greenLightButton : missing value
property greenLightImage : missing value
```

Next add a "square" button to your window. This will show your image. Make it the size you want for the green image. In the attributes inspector, uncheck "bordered" for the button. It will basically look invisible at this point. Hook up the greenLightButton property to that button. Next add this code.

```
on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
   set greenLightImage to NSImage's imageNamed_("green.png")
end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

on isActivationOn()
   set isOn to false
   try
      do shell script "/usr/bin/defaults read com.apple.iTunes StoreActivationMode"
      if result is "1" then set isOn to true
   end try
   return isOn
end isActivationOn
```

Then anywhere in your code, probably in your button methods and in applicationWillFinishLaunching, you want something like this...

```
if (isActivationOn()) then
   greenLightButton's setImage_(greenLightImage)
else
   greenLightButton's setImage_(missing value)
end
```